# Using one button to pull information from several panels

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

I'm building this form that I want to be able to change what fields are displayed based on what setting you select.

There's going to be 3 panels, first with text fields gathering information, second for notes, third for a checklist. The main frame will add those panels onto it and use one buttons to gather the information from each panel and compile it into a text area so you can just copy/paste it after it's been formatted.

So the problem I'm having is getting the information passed over to the main frame. I have created a formlistener to pass information from the form using an object FormEvent I have created which will carry over the necessary information. I have then created a method in the form to pull the relevant information depending on which form is being used at the time. My problem is getting that method to call properly. This is the `ActionListener` for the button:

```
confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    form.getUbntInfo(); // this is where i have it set
    form.setFormListener(new FormListener() {
          // would like it to go here so that it creates the event 
          // object to pass before               
          // it passes the information, but it causes compile error here
        public void formEventOccured(FormEvent e) {
            String complaint = e.getComplaint();
            String ping = e.getPing();
            String ap = e.getAp();
                signal0 = e.getSignal0();
                signal1 = e.getSignal1();
                chain0 = e.getChain0();
                chain1 = e.getChain1();
                sinr0 = e.getSinr0();
                sinr1 = e.getSinr1();
                sinr0 = e.getLan();
                System.out.println("local signal: " + signal0);
        }
    });
```

Essentially the `getUbntInfo();` method needs to have a formListener set so that it can pass create the object to pass along the information. As it stands I can press the button twice and it passes the information the second time but it will not do it the first time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do not add the listener inside the `actionPerformed` method, try setting it **before** the button is pressed, that is, same time when setting action listener (while constructing theGUI)

Comment: What is a `FormEvent`? NVM, post a [mre] & all shall be clear.

Comment: Generally, you create a data model with Java classes to hold the information from one or more input panels.  Then, when the user presses the button, you have all the information in one place.

Comment: I have figured it out, thank you guys. What I did was implement the form listener into the main frame, and set the listener prior to gathering data like user85421 suggested. Now everything is passing down just fine